# "Elberich mi ripugna" è una frase ambigua?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Elberich mi ripugna.

è una frase ambigua?

Cioè, supponiamo un parlante pronunci quella frase, come possiamo capire se è Elberich che ripugna al parlante o il parlante che ripugna a Elberich?

Comment: Puoi chiarire un po' meglio? In che senso potrebbe significare che il parlante ripugna a Elberich?

Comment: Il verbo _utterare_ in quale dizionario si trova?

Comment: Penso che il potenziale problema sia capire se il parlante sta parlando di un certo Elberich esterno alla conversazione o se si sta rivolgendo ad Elberich stesso dandogli del Lei. Nel secondo caso ci sarebbe stata una virgola tra "Elberich" e "mi" (e nel parlato lo si sarebbe capito dall'intonazione), quindi no, non può essere mai ambiguo.

Answer (score 6):

No, non è una frase ambigua. Vediamo perché:

- La parola *Elberich* non è preceduta da nessuna preposizione. Di conseguenza può essere solo un soggetto o un complemento oggetto (ok, ok, sto semplificando.. in questo caso è chiaro però).
- La parola *mi* è un pronome personale complemento (mentre il pronome personale soggetto sarebbe *io*), di conseguenza non può essere il soggetto. Senza altre preposizioni può svolgere il ruolo di complemento oggetto o di complemento di termine.
- *ripugna* è un verbo coniugato alla terza persona singolare. Quindi il soggetto non può essere *mi* in ogni caso, che è un pronome di prima persona. In più è un verbo intransitivo, di conseguenza non può avere un complemento oggetto. Quindi *mi* è necessariamente un complemento di termine.

Da notare che in quest'analisi non ho utilizzato la posizione delle parole; ad esempio *Mi ripugna Elberich* ha esattamente lo stesso significato. La posizione delle parole in italiano spesso comunica l'enfasi invece del ruolo grammaticale (come ad esempio è comune in inglese).

Finalmente vediamo una frase quasi identica ma dal diverso significato:

*Elberich, mi ripugna!*

In questa frase la virgola separa *Elberich* da *mi ripugna*. Di fatto qui *Elberich* viene a diventare un'invocazione ad un ipotetico interlocutore o qualche altro tipo di escalamazione. A seconda del contesto questa frase potrebbe rappresentare una persona che si lamenta con Elberich di una cosa che gli ripugna oppure *Elberich* potrebbe essere un nome collegato alla cosa che ripugna (ad esempio *uccidere Elberich* o *sposare Elberich*). In particolare, al contrario del primo esempio, è impossibile dedurre senza ulteriori informazioni se l'opinione del parlante su Elberich sia positiva o negativa.

Comment: Secondo me, per avere il secondo significato non basta una virgola. Occorrerebbe utilizzare il punto interrogativo, per sottolineare la risposta ad una domanda come in:  
> Cosa pensi di Elberich?  
> Elberich? Mi ripugna!  
Una seconda opzione è voler sottolineare una riflessione del parlante, e qui metterei i puntini sospensivi:  
> Elberich... mi ripugna!

Comment: Suppongo sia più che altro una questione di stile. Io non penso che utilizzerei mai il punto e virgola in un periodo così breve, al massimo il punto interrogativo. In ogni caso si tratta di sfumature di significato per cui l'interpretazione della frase dipende fortemente dal contesto.